# The field date must be a date in mvc in chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm doing a simple MVC4 Internet application, which allows to add some items to the categories.

Here is what i've done so far.

I've a datepicker in mvc view. The script for the datepicker is like this.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dtItemDueDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            minDate: 0
        });
    });
</script>
```

My model property :

```
        [DisplayName("Item DueDate")]
        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? dtItemDueDate { get; set; }
        public char charCompleted { get; set; }
```

and in my view i've done this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.dtItemDueDate)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.dtItemDueDate)
```

The error is like this:

```
The field Item DueDate must be a date.
```

The strange this is that it does work in IE and mozilla, but doesnot work in Chrome.

I found many posts on SO, but none of them help

Any ideas/suggestions ?

Comment: Is this the same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966244/jquery-datepicker-chrome

Comment: @RowanFreeman yes rowan. I'll look into the answer.

Comment: @RowanFreeman rowan thanks. It does work. Please post the answer in that post here as well. The link may break any time.. Thanks a million

Comment: I got the same error in firefox

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Editor note: This answer is no longer valid, as of jQuery 1.9 (2013) the `$.browser` method has been removed**

---

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966244/jquery-datepicker-chrome) it's a known quirk with Webkit-based browsers.

One solution is to modify `jquery.validate.js` by finding the function `date: function (value, element)` and put this code in it:

```js
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    //ES - Chrome does not use the locale when new Date objects instantiated:
    var d = new Date();
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
}
else {
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
}
```

Comment: +1 to the user who posted answer and to you as well for finding the threading, coz i didn't find that thread :P

Comment: The $.browser method has been deprecated for a while and has been  removed as of jQuery 1.9.

Comment: The above is not the correct approach for fixing this problem. Firstly you should never change the jquery validate source code secondly as stated above $.browser.webkit is deprecated. The way to achieve this fix for this is to simply add this jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    if (value) {
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
        } catch (ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

Comment: @MaximGershkovich that doesn't work for me, as `$.datapicker` is null which throws me into the exception, returning false for "02/05/2003" (Chrome 38).

Comment: **I do not recommend this method.** As has been stated many times now this solution is not ideal and completely outdated. If you still have this issue please find a better solution.

Comment: This fails normal validation on other fields so [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633471/mvc4-datatype-date-editorfor-wont-display-date-value-in-chrome-fine-in-interne) is the **working solution** , hope helps.

Comment: This work for my dates dd/mm/yyyy: 

//Corrige o BUG de validação do chrome  do campo Date no formato dd/mm/yyyy 

jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    var d = value.split("/");
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date((/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) ? d[1] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[2] : value));
};

Comment: This work for my dates dd/mm/yyyy: 

//Corrige o BUG de validação do chrome  do campo Date no formato dd/mm/yyyy 

//fonte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546971/mvc-4-how-to-validate-a-non-us-date-with-client-validation

jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || moment(value, "DD/MM/YYYY", true).isValid();
};

Answer (score 48):

Without changing jquery.validate.js, you can use the code snip below in `$(document).ready()`:

```
jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
    if (isChrome) {
        var d = new Date();
        return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
    } else {
        return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
    }
};
```

Comment: Seems to be the best solution, without modifying the jquery file which is not recomended

Comment: I would give you a million up votes if I could - works perfectly! Thank you :)

Comment: great answer!! thanks Kyle

Comment: This fails normal validation on other fields so [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633471/mvc4-datatype-date-editorfor-wont-display-date-value-in-chrome-fine-in-interne) is the **working solution** , hope helps.

Answer (score 8):

Rowan Freeman solution wont work for me since `.toLocaleDateString(value)` doesn't parse `value` strings

here's the solution i came up with =>
in jquery.validate.js find this function definition: "date: function (value, element)" and replace the code with:

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date
date: function (value, element) {
    var d = value.split("/");
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date((/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) ? d[1] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[2] : value));
},
```

Comment: This works if you are using jQuery 1.9, but it needs tweaking if you use different date format and/or separator.

Comment: You can fix it without changing jquery itself like so, overriding the default behaviour:
`jQuery.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element, params) {
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            return true;
        };

        return /^\d{4}[\/\-]\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$/.test(value);

    }, '');`

Comment: Nice catch. Same issue for me, this one is working!

Comment: Great comment @PawełG. Finally helped solve my problem!

Answer (score 8):

Below is the working code that may helpful for some one to fix the date picker issue in chrome and safari:
Model:

```
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @type = "text", @class = "fromDate" })
```

js:

```
$(function () {
    checkSupportForInputTypeDate();

    $('#StartDate').datepicker({        
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });    
});

//Function to configure date format as the native date type from chrome and safari browsers is clashed with jQuery ui date picker.
function checkSupportForInputTypeDate() {
    jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
        var isSafari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);
        if (isSafari || isChrome) {
            var d = new Date();
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
        } else {
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's [Maxim Gershkovich's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706455/1366033#comment39467632_15707341) spelled out a little more:

```js
jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    if (value) {
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
        } catch (ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

**Notes**:

- This depends on the [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) method that comes with jQuery UI
- This is actually more robust that the native date validation that comes with jQueryValidate.

  According to the docs on [date validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/date-method/):

  > Returns true if the value is a valid date. Uses JavaScript's built-in Date to test if the date is valid, and therefore **does no sanity checks**. Only the format must be valid, not the actual date, eg 30/30/2008 is a valid date.

  Whereas [`parseDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-parseDate) will check that the date is valid and actually exists.

Comment: Great thanks @KyleMit this is the only one which worked for me both in Chrome & Firefox (both were causing issue)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing from **DateTime** to **String**.

This is the best solution for a good maintance that I can think at the moment.