# MVC 4 - IE 8 - jquery - bundling date error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

The MVC 4.0 application works fine with IE 8, IE 9 and Chrome when the  compilation `debug ="true"`.

When set to compilation `debug="false"` and after adding `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` in the **BundleConfig.cs** for the release, a date error appears on IE 8.

> The field  *field name* Date must be a date

On IE 9 and in Chrome the date fields are working fine.

So I suspected bundling issues, but when I checked the script bundle using developer tool - script tab, I can see the below mentioned part of the script at the end, which I understand that the bundle is delivered properly.

```
$('.datefield').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

Further the scripts works fine on IE 9.0 and Chrome, so I believe the bundling is working fine.

When in `debug = true` mode, the script works in IE 8.0 without any issues. If it is a jQuery script compatibility issue, then here also we should get error, right?

I verified that the script files dumped into browser in the debug mode is there in the bundleConfig Add().

Please help me to identify a fix for the IE 8.0.

Adding the script files I see in `debug = true` mode.

```
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/aml.js"></script>
```

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Sushil, I updated the question with the js file version.

Comment: does this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706455/the-field-date-must-be-a-date-in-mvc-in-chrome??

Comment: @Sushil, I don't think it is related to the link given by you.

Comment: oh. i thought it was a similar issue

Comment: @CoOl, thanks for the edit.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for testing?