# The field 'Date' must be a date MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

Im facing this error when im using my jQuery datepicker.

jQuery:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    defaultDate: +7,
    autoSize: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
});
```

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

So I want the date format to be like `dd.MM.yyyy`, and when I select the date using the datepicker it is correctly added to the field. But also in the same second, an validation error appears saying `The field 'Date' must be a date`.

I did test with writing manually the date in the format `dd/MM/yy` and then it looks like it is working. So somewhere the validator looks for that format, but I cant find out where to modify it.

Comment: Did you get this working? If not, you can try my answer.

Comment: Don't you need quotes around the +7 (like '+7')?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using chrome? Can be a jquery.validate.js issue, please have a look to this [Jquery Datepicker Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966244/jquery-datepicker-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

DisplayFormat won't be the format in which is accepted in the validation. I would suggest using a regular expression to validate this if you want something with periods in there.

```
[DisplayName("Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"PUT REGEX HERE", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date")] // below is a link
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

[Some common expressions here.](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/226-how-to-validate-traditional-date-formats-with-regular-expressions/)

Also, I would suggest being consistent in format when going from the c# to the js.

**You have in JS:**

```
dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
```

**You might want:**

```
dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
```

You could also just change the DisplayFormat attribute on the model to just be dd.MM.yy as well. Just a thought!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the answer provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17968454/4955259 appears to be working for me for date format dd.mm.yy (add the script after jquery.validate.js).

```
jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    var d = value.split(".");
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date((/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) ? d[1] + "." + d[0] + "." + d[2] : value));
};
```