# The field 'BirthDate' must be a date MVC 4, internet explorer 11

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-11

The same question were asked in this thread [The field 'Date' must be a date MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134357/the-field-date-must-be-a-date-mvc-4) but I have slightly different problem.I got the error while using internet explorer 11, not able to figure it out.
Here is the property in my model

> [Required]
>    [Display( Name = "Birth Date")]
>    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
>    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

and jQuery is

> $(function () {
>           dateFormat: $.datepicker.RFC_1123;
>         $('#BirthDate').attr('readonly', true);
>           $('#BirthDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "d/M/yy" });
>       });

and code for textbox

> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RFI.BirthDate, "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}", new { datepicker = true, @class = "textbox_medium", id = "BirthDate" })

to support this format I wrote the following code in jquery.validate.js file, in the function definition of  "date: function (value, element)"

> if ($.browser.webkit) {
>   
>                   //ES - Chrome does not use the locale when new Date objects instantiated:
>                   var d = new Date();
>   
>                   return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
>               }
>               else {
>   
>       
>             return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
>          
>      }

The mentioned code works correctly in Crome but doesn't works in internet explorer 11. Frstly it gives the error for webkit, then I changed the definition of a date function (replace code with previous definition) still it gives an error of "The Birthday must be date "

Comment: Is it a javascript error or your form is posted to the server and you get an error from the server? If you put a breakpoint in your action (to which you submit this form) do you get this field correctly populated in the model?

Comment: @DenisShulepov It's not JavaScript error, since I removed the specific part related to chrome. When I press "Save" button on that page I got error The "BirthDate" must be Date, since I mentioned in the model [DataType(DataType.DateTime)] above the declaration of BirthDate.

Answer (score 0):

I did a full test of your scenario. The error occurs in IE in jquery.validate.js on the following check:

```
    // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date
    date: function( value, element ) {
        return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value).toString());
    },
```

For quick prove you can try to write the following in Console in both IE and Chrome:

```
new Date('01/Jun/2001');
```

In Chrome you'll get a valid date and in IE invalid.

To fix the issue - change the format in your date picket to a default one "dd/mm/yy":

```
$('#BirthDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
```