# Unable to validate date format on edit view in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, date, asp.net-mvc-5

This question has been asked before but the answers do not solve my problem.
The problem is that I am always getting the following error with **datetime** field.

> The field Created Time must be a date.

**My Try**

Here is modal where I have set date format

```
[Display(Name = "Created Time")]
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedTime { get; set; }
```

View code

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedTime, "Timesheet Date")
    <div class='input-group date' id='Datetimepicker1'>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreatedTime, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span>
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

In js

```
$('#CreatedTime').removeAttr("data-val-date");
$('#Datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' });
```

Also tried to change in `jquery.validate.js` funcation `date: function (value, element)` as below but but unable to solve the issue.

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    //ES - Chrome does not use the locale when new Date objects instantiated:
    var d = new Date();
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
}
else {
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
}
```

Visited links

[The field must be a date - DatePicker validation fails in Chrome - mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20548335/2798643)

[The field date must be a date in mvc in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15707341/2963609)

And many more links and sites but unable to solve issue

Comment: Which date picker are you using - jquery-ui? (and do not use `$('#CreatedTime').removeAttr("data-val-date");`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am using bootstrap datetimepicker to display date

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) - try adding the script after you load jquery and bootstrap (but not inside document.ready)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try it**

Keep this js code out side of `$(document).ready();`. only inside of `<script>Here</script>` tag.

```
    $(function () {
        $.validator.addMethod('date',
        function (value, element) {
            if (this.optional(element)) {
                return true;
            }
            var ok = true;
            try {
                $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
            }
            catch (err) {
                ok = false;
            }
            return ok;
        });
        $("#ID").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeYear: true });
    });
```

Hope it will be helpful. In my case it is working.

Comment: I have put this code inside of document.ready function but not working

Comment: Please put this code outside of document.ready function. just put it inside of <script>//Code.....</script> tag than it will be working hope so.

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar, You need to edit you answer and remove the `$(function () {`line

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry but when I remove your suggested line than getting error :- `$(...).datepicker is not a function` so i am not removing it.

Comment: That would depend on where you have rendered this in the view. As you have said yourself above it should not be in `document.ready` (`$(function ()` is a shortcut for `document.ready`). In your example, the last line (`$("#ID").datepicker({ ... });`) needs to be separated out and put inside `document.ready` if its not at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

(Put that on _Layout.cshtml)

```
$(function () {
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            //Fix chrom Asp.Net MVC jQuery validation: The field "Myfield" must be a date.
            var ischrom = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
            if (ischrom) {
                if ($.browser.webkit) {
                    //Chrome does not use the locale when new Date objects instantiated:
                    var d = new Date();
                    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
                }
                else {
                    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
            }
        };

    });
```

credits to: http://blog.mohnady.com/2015/02/fix-aspnet-mvc-chrome-jquery-validation.html