# DateTime Parse Issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime

i have an issue with validating datetime textbox,

the datetime is a display date in the following way:

```
public class Article : TblAbstract<int> {
                private DateTime displayDate;

                [DisplayName("وقت الظهور")] // Display date in arabic
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt}")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Editable(true, AllowInitialValue = true)]

// the error message means: display date is not in a correct format and it must be 2016-09-30 06:26:35 am

        [DateTimeFormatValidation(ErrorMessage = "وقت الظهور ليس بالشكل الصحيح، عليك إعتماد هذا الشكل 2016-09-30 06:26:35 am")]
                public DateTime DisplayDate {
                        get { return displayDate; }
                        set { displayDate = value; }
                }
}


public class AddArticleViewsModel : AdminGViewsModel {
    private List<ArticleItem> articleItemList;
    private Article newArticle;

    public AddArticleViewsModel() : base(typeof(AddArticleViewsModel)) {
        newArticle = new Article();
        newArticle.DisplayDate = DateTime.Now;
        articleItemList = new List<ArticleItem>();


    }

    public List<ArticleItem> ArticleItemList {
        get { return articleItemList; }
        set { articleItemList = value; }
    }

    public Article NewArticle {
        get { return newArticle; }
        set { newArticle = value; }
    }
}
```

i'm using this jquery control over the textbox:

jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-1.6.1.js from the website

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker

the javascript used:

```
<script>
                        $("#txtDisplayDate").datetimepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss tt'
            });
</script>
```

the html and razor for the textbox:

```
<div class="lblMsg">
            // arabic means: warning you to fix the following issues
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "تنبيه، عليك إصلاح الأخطاء التالية:")
</div>

 <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewArticle.DisplayDate, new { id = "lblDisplayDate", name = "lblDisplayDate", Class = "lblAddArticle", For = "txtDisplayDate" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewArticle.DisplayDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt}", new { id = "txtDisplayDate", name = "txtDisplayDate", Class = "inputAddArticle" })
    </p>
```

This works fine over all browsers **except FIREFOX (Firefox 43.04 64-Bit Edition)**

see these images:

Image for the designed page having the issue:
i.stack.imgur.com/EMLa4.png

Image to show the issue happen in firefox:
i.stack.imgur.com/UGKRc.png

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284385/the-field-must-be-a-date-datepicker-validation-fails-in-chrome-mvc Solutions may help

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706455/the-field-date-must-be-a-date-in-mvc-in-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution to the problem is to use:
Razor:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewArticle.DisplayDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt}", new { id = "txtDisplayDate", name = "txtDisplayDate", Class = "inputAddArticle", @Type="datetime", @Data_Val_Date = "وقت الظهور ليس بالنسق المطلوب، عليك إعتماد هذا الشكل 2016-01-30 11:30:20 am" })
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            if (value) {
                try {
                    var dateTest = /^[1-2][0-9]{3}-[0-1][1-9]-[0-3][0-9] [0-1][1-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [APap][mM]$/;
                    return this.optional(element) || dateTest.test(value);
                } catch (ex) {
                    alert(ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };
}
```