# jquery datepicker throwing error in different browsers with mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

my view to display date from database

```
<div class="input-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.domain_renew_date, "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}", new { @type = "datetime", @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.domain_renew_date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

my javascript for datepicker

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="datetime"]').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/MM/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "c-10:c+10"
        });
    });
</script>
```

model where the property is declared

```
[Display(Name = "Date of Renewal")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[RequiredIf("domain_flag", "1", ErrorMessage = "Enter Renew Date")]
public DateTime? domain_renew_date { get; set; }
```

in web.config

```
<system.web>
  <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
</system.web>
```

This is working perfectly fine in chrome and Firefox. But gives the following error in IE and Safari

> The field Date of Renewal must be a date

What changes can be done in the code to make it work perfectly fine in all the browsers?

Comment: instead of `$('input[type="datetime"]')` use same class for all elements on which you want to show date-picker and then do like this `$('.class-name').datepicker({`. I hope this will work for all browers

Comment: Or take help from this:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33591786/4248328

Comment: its still giving a error

Comment: in both I m getting error in IE browser

Comment: check different solutions of this thread :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29273831/4248328.

Comment: I tried all possible solutions. Fails to work in IE browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error got solved by adding the following code

```
<script>
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
     'date',
     function (value, element, params) {
         if (this.optional(element)) return true;
         var ok = true;
         try {
             $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-M-yy',value);
         } catch (err) {
             ok = false;
         }
         return ok;
     },
      'Must enter date in dd-M-yy format.'
  );
```