# Azure app web service date format issue after published the code

Tags: javascript, .net, azure, model-view-controller, datetimepicker

My project is in MVC. I am using bootstrap datetime picker for selecting the date from web and it is working on my local machine, but after publishing the code on Azure, I am getting a date format validation error.

JavaScript:

```
$('#DateofBooking').datetimepicker({format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'});
```

The validation message I see:

[image: Screenshot of validation message: "The field must be a date."]

Comment: Have you already checked out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284385/the-field-must-be-a-date-datepicker-validation-fails-in-chrome-mvc?

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript. http://javascriptisnotjava.io