# Asp.net MVC DateTime Culture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, culture

I am using my Windows machine in English, and when i looked at the MsSql DB, my date time is in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

But i want this format in `dd/mm/yyyy`.

There is no problem about `datepicker` that i am using, i can change the input type, but unless i change my culture, i am not able to insert my date fields.

I have already tried to put culture tag into my `web.config` but still i am not able to insert the date as `29/2/2014`. It is accepting only `2/29/2014`.

What is the best way to resolve this problem without depending the server language ?

Comment: Solved :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966244/jquery-datepicker-chrome